# Auto layout creates black space under resized button

Tags: swift, autolayout

[image]

There is a black space under the button here caused by autolayout resizing

My auto layouts are to the edge of the view on left and right side and then it maintains the aspect ratio and is also to the bottom of the collection view above

This only happens when the display zoom is set to on, this is the look of the resizing when that is on

Answer (score 0):

open your IB and click on the Button , on bottom in Resolve Auto Layout issues try Add Missing Constraints , and make sure when you click on a button the Constraint Lines are all blue

Comment: The constraint lines are all blue, there are no missing constraints

Comment: did you apply Reset to Suggested Constraints ?

Comment: or Did you try using a different simulator Like iPhone 5s?